# What is the rule for array assignment to a slice related with its capacity?

Tags: go

```
    a := [...]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4} // an array
    sa := a[1:3] // sa == []int{1, 2}        cap(sa) == 4
    sb := a[:2] // sb == []int{0, 1}        cap(sb) == 5
    sc := a[2:] // sc == []int{2, 3, 4}        cap(sc) == 3
    sd := a[:] // sd == []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}  cap(sd) == 5
```

does my conclusion correct? that `slice capacity = len(array) - [first index]` and doesn't matter regarding the `[second index]`?

Comment: Such questions are easily answered by consulting the language spec.

Comment: You can test your assumptions with the [`cap` built-in](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity).

Comment: @Volker actually I got difficulty to find the language spec of this case. could you show me?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slice is a view of an underlying array. Given an array length of `n`, if the slice starts at `arr[0]`, the capacity of the slice is `n`, if the slice starts at `arr[1]` then the capacity of the slice if `n-1`, etc. regardless of the second index. The second index you give when you slice an array specifies the slice length, not capacity.